# Plone issue with versioning - Object's versions lost on cut and paste

Tags: versioning, plone, zope

Plone 2.5.1

Zope 2.9.5

CMFEditions 1.0rc1

If you create a page in a folder at plonesite root and create a new version of it, once you cut and paste that page to a new location the version will be lost.

I've tested this on zope 2.10 and Plone 3.0 and its no longer an issue but I'm interested to see if anyone knows a way to fix this on the versions I mentioned above

Thanks

Comment: Which version is lost? Ths old or the new version?

Comment: all versions will be lost, you can create as many versions as you want of the page, yuo access them from a versions tab at the top of the page, once the doc is moved and you access the versions page through the tab, all versions have dissapeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading CMFEditions to the version that ships with Plone 3.x? As you're pointing out, it's fixed already, so that might work.

Comment: If you could specify your tweaks here (in a separate answer maybe) or on ths issue tracker, others could benefit from it. :)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, it's reported in the [issue tracker](http://plone.org/products/cmfeditions/issues/41). However, there's no solution listed there.